# App is not running retina in Xcode simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, retina-display

I got a project from my coworker, let's name it as `ProjectB`, The weirdest part of this project is when I run this project in iPhone 6, I can see it's not retina. 
I am trying to figure out how to make this project runs as retina. For test, I created an another empty project `Demo`. And then I copied a UITableViewController from `ProjectB` and paste it in the `Demo` project. When I run `Demo`, it's retina obviously. I make two snapshot from `ProjectB` and `Demo` to compare them:

`Demo` runs in simulator look like this
[image: Demo]
`ProjectB` runs in simulator look like this
[image: ProjectB]

As you can see, the cell looks fine in `Demo` but not good in `ProjectB`. I have set the layout constraint for their common UITableViewController. Both projects are using the same UITableViewController in a storyboard.

So, `ProjectB` definitely is not running as retina. I have looked the project setting, deployment target is iOS 7.0, runs in iPhone 6 simulator. What else should I look at?

Comment: Here, what u mean by retina.? how you are relating it with screen shots?

Comment: both screenshots look the same to me

Comment: It looks as if the *Demo* project is running with the iPhone **6 plus** simulator and the *ProjectB* is running with the iPhone **6** simulator. Make sure you have selected exactly the same device for the simulator in Xcode.

Comment: @Codo Gosh. I just said I am running the same iPhone 6 simulator. I am pretty sure because If I am running different simulator, I have to actually to select iPhone 6 plus. would I?

Comment: @MithunR. I guess it's retina. Have you tried to download a app and run it in your iPhone device. It looks smaller and not retina like any other app? Then that's what I am talking about.

Comment: @Nishant Have you noticed the cell, the first one looks fine. But the 2nd one, the layout is all messed up.

Comment: @yongho: its not the layout but the size of the string is too large for that label.

Answer (score 0):

The iPhone 6+ renders internally using @3x assets at a virtual resolution of 2208×1242 (with 736x414 points), then samples that down for display

In order to determine iphone 6+ screen in xcode , it is necessary have a picture Default-736h@3x.png

And remove Launch Screen file

Below is the list of launch image sizes and their corresponding filenames, again with iPhone 6/6 Plus bolded for reference:

Default.png: 320 x 480

Default@2x.png: 640 x 960

Default-568h@2x.png: 640 x 1136

Default-667h@2x.png: 750 x 1334 (iPhone 6, Portrait)

Default-736h@3x.png: 1242 x 2208 (iPhone 6 Plus, Portrait)

Default-Landscape-568h@2x.png: 1136 x 640

Default-Landscape-667h@2x.png: 1334 x 750 (iPhone 6, Landscape)

Default-Landscape-736h@3x.png: 2208 x 1242 (iPhone 6 Plus, Landscape)

Default-Portrait.png: 768 x 1024

Default-Portrait@2x.png: 1536 x 2048

Default-Landscape.png: 1024 x 768

Default-Landscape@2x.png: 2048 x 1536

Or use  Launch Screen file  @3x / @2x screens  for 6 Plus/Phone 6

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the launch screen is not set. And I figured not give it a try. And then I set select the launch screen. It worked. It is running retina.